# VBA "For" loop not working

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have two spreadsheets, the first is a master phone list, the second is a user phone list of names tied to phone numbers, i am trying to write a for loop that will find the matching numbers then copy the users name to an empty column on the master list to identify all available numbers. I'm not sure if i am going the right way about it though. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub temp()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Set x = Sheet4.Range("A1:A1300")
For i = 2 To 500
If Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 4)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way is it going wrong?

Comment: this **Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1)** seems odd to me! Especially the **x**

Comment: X doesn't appear to be defined. You should add `Option Explicit` to your code modules.

Comment: @ckuhn203 x is set to a range actually. its not declared (as you noticed) but its assigned at least

Comment: I missed that @mehow. My apologies.

Comment: Set X = Sheet4.... is assigning a range to x whereas the Cells(x,1) is expecting x to be an integer. Correct that first. If you meant x to take value of A1 to A1300 you would have to use two For loops. and A1 to A1300 should always contain integers. And also it should be Sheet4.Range("A"&counter).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do can be handled by a VLOOKUP worksheet formula.

In the cells of the column you are trying to populate, enter,

`=VLOOKUP([cell containing phone number to lookup],[range to lookup on],[column number of result beginning from 1],FALSE)`

So, I think you want, in Sheet3 cell D2,

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet4!$A$1:$C$1300,3,False)`

Comment: i didnt even think to try a vlookup